The relation between spectral function, Green function and particle number in many-body systems
The spectral function is defined as the imaginary part of Green function multiplied by $-2$ (Ref. Mahan. Many-Particle Physics 3ed. Kluwer Academic, 1990.),
$$
A(\mathbf{k},\mathrm{i} \omega_n) = -2 \mathrm{Im} G(\mathbf{k},\mathrm{i} \omega_n),
$$
where $\omega_n = (2n+1)\pi T$ (with $n$ and integer) is Matsubara frequency, $T$ is temperature. The particle number can be get from spectral function,
$$
\begin{align}
n(\mathbf{k}) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,A(\mathbf{k},\omega+\mathrm{i} 0^{+}) n_{F}(\omega)
=-2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\mathrm{Im} G(\mathbf{k}, \omega+\mathrm{i} 0^{+}) n_{F}(\omega)
. \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $n_F$ is the Fermi distribution function.
I also see in some papers (e.g. PhysRevA.73.023618 (2006) and PhysRevA.79.053640(2009)) that the particle number can be calculated by
$$
n(\mathbf{k}) = T\sum_n G(\mathbf{k}, \mathrm{i}\omega_n) e^{\mathrm{i}\omega_n \tau},\tag{2}
$$
where $\tau\to 0^{+}$.
My questions is how can we derived Eq. (2) from Eq. (1) mathematically?
If we take the Green function as free Green function,
$$
G_0(\mathbf{k}, \mathrm{i}\omega_n) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{i}\omega_n - k^2/(2m)},
$$
I can prove Eq. (1) and Eq. (2) is equivalent. But I can not prove this for a general Green function
$$
G(\mathbf{k}, \mathrm{i}\omega_n) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{i}\omega_n - k^2/(2m) - \Sigma(\mathbf{k}, \mathrm{i}\omega_n)},
$$
where $\Sigma(\mathbf{k}, \mathrm{i}\omega_n)$ is self-energy.

The one particle Matsubara Green functions is defined via imaginary time ordering for bosons and fermions as
$
G(\tau) = -\langle T(c(\tau) c^\dagger) \rangle = -\theta(\tau) \langle c(\tau) c^\dagger \rangle \mp \theta(-\tau) \langle c^\dagger c(\tau) \rangle
$
Therefore we can obtain the particle number as
$
 n =  \langle c^\dagger c \rangle = \mp \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} G(-\epsilon) = \mp \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i \omega} e^{- i \omega (-\epsilon)} G(i \omega) = \mp \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i \omega} e^{ i \omega \epsilon} G(i \omega)
$
